# Wrapping text within align

Tags: spacing, equations, align, wrap

I am writing Flashcards for the upcomming finals.

To describe the equations I use the `align*` environment like this:

```
\begin{align*}
    x_+ &: \text{ Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen funktionelle Gruppen protoniert sind}\\
    x_n &: \text{ Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen die Ladung mehr oder weniger ausgeglichen ist}\\
    x_- &: \text{ Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen funktionelle Gruppen deprotoniert sind }
\end{align*}
```

long descriptions are going over the margin. (using `a6paper`)

is there any way to wrap the text within the `align*` environment other than this:

```
\begin{align*}
    x_+ &:      \text{ Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen }\\
        &:\quad \text{funktionelle Gruppen protoniert sind}\\
    x_n &:      \text{ Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen}\\
        &:\quad \text{die Ladung mehr oder weniger ausgeglichen ist}\\
    x_- &:      \text{ Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen}\\
        &:\quad \text{funktionelle Gruppen deprotoniert sind }
\end{align*}
```

It should provide the same behavior like centering and stuff, just with wrapping. Centering is important to make things clearer.

Comment: This looks more like a `{description}` list to me

Comment: @cgnieder, i already tried that but looked kinda wierd because it isn't centerd and generates "ugly" output with large itemlabels

Comment: Well, you can always customize such a list with [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). (I guess by “not centered” you mean “no additional margins”?)

Comment: `enumitem` could solve the problem, i'll try that. "additional margins" is what i ment, right.

Comment: I used `paralist` and `enumitem` works fine would be great to set the left and right margins even. I tried `[leftmargin=1em, rightmargin=1em]` to let it look like the `align*` but it didn't work out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a `{description}` list to me. In order to get the required margins one can use [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). The key is section *3.3 More on horizontal spacing* of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem). The code below could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{indenteddesc}{description}{1}
\setlist[indenteddesc]{
  leftmargin=5em,  % labelindent+labelwidth+labelsep
  rightmargin=3em,
  labelindent=3em, % set equal to rightmargin
  labelwidth=1.5em,% choose a width the labels fit in
  labelsep=.5em
}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{indenteddesc}
 \item[$x_+$] Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen funktionelle Gruppen protoniert
   sind
 \item[$x_n$] Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen die Ladung mehr oder weniger
   ausgeglichen ist
 \item[$x_-$] Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen funktionelle Gruppen deprotoniert
   sind
\end{indenteddesc}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works fine with long entries but does not behave like `align*` while using shorter entries.

Comment: @Timebandit Well, of course, since this one has fixed indents. I'm not really able to see why this is a problem? It might very well be you won't get an exact equivalent for `{align}` with any solution.

Comment: I think you're right, in this case this is the best way to handle it. I just reduced the `itemsep` to make it look more compact.

Comment: @Timebandit If you want the whole thing visually centered even if the lines are shorter you can always put [a frame around it](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or something...

Comment: Sounds right. Is there any possibility to center enumerations?

Comment: An enumeration list is essentially the same as a description list or an itemize list. They all use LaTeX's `{list}` internally.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with a `tabularx` environment instead of `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
$x_+$ & Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen funktionelle Gruppen protoniert sind\\
    $x_n$ & Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen die Ladung mehr oder weniger ausgeglichen ist\\
    $x_-$ & Molenbruch von Enzymen, bei denen funktionelle Gruppen deprotoniert sind
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `\noindent` before `\begin{tabularx}`

Comment: @egreg thanks, I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Like `description` this works for long entries, but for shorter entries, where wrap is not necessary, it shows a behavior different from `align*`